# Can i Retrain Inception's Final Layer using depth images from Kinect.?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, kinect

I like to know whether I can use data set of signs that is made using Kinect to retrain inception's final layer like mentioned in the Tensor Flow tutorial website that uses ordinary RGB images.I am new to this field. Opinions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No. You cannot just fine tune only the last layer. But you can fine tune the whole pre-trained network.". The first layers of the pre-trained network is looking for RGB features. Your depth frames will hardly provide enough entropy to match that. Your options are:

1. If the recognised/tracked objects (hands) are not masked and you have actual depth data for the background, you can train from scratch on depth images with few contrast stretching and data whitening ((x-mu)/sigma). This will take very long time for the ivy league networks like Inception and ResNet. Also, keep in mind that most python based deep learning frameworks rely on PIL image loaders which by default assumes images are of 8bits channels mapped in the range [0, 1]. These image loaders cast all 16bits pixels ones.
2. If the recognised/tracked object (hands) are masked which means your background is set to the same value or barely have gradient in it, the network will overfit on the silhouette of the object because this is where the strongest edges are. The solution for this is to colorise the depth image using normal maps, HSA, HSV, JET colour coding to convert it into 3x8bits channeled image. This makes the training converge much faster and in my late experiments we found that you can fine tune the ivy league networks on the colorised depth.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to this field.I would like to suggest you to read what is [transfer learning](http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/) all the three types mentioned.I would like to tell you to apply any of the mentioned forms of transfer learning basing on your data set.If your data set is very similar to the type of model you are using then you can pass through last layers.If you data is not similar you have to tune the existing model and use it.

As the layers of the neural networks increases the data specific feature extraction increases so you have to take care of the specific layers if your dataset is not very similar to the pre-built model dataset. The starting layers will contain more generic features.